# How to close Enhanced ad privacy popup in chrome using python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMtLW.png

I'm getting this popup when I use python selenium. I have used  `chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-features=EnhancedAdBlocking') , chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")` to turn it off.But it's not working!

How to Close this popup?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-features=PrivacySandboxSettings4')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following key in registry:
DWORD: `"BlockThirdPartyCookies"` in `"HKLM:\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\Recommended"` (create path if it doesn't exist) and set to value to `1`