# Selenium - ChromeDriver - close the 'What's new' UI

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

i am literally stuck at how to hide this window in the new Chrome Version 120, i can't find any flag to add as startup argument.
i found the flag below on a separate thread but ig it's outdated or deprecated:
--disable-features=ChromeWhatsNewUI
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsehB.png)

tried the same flag and it didn't work

Comment: Try asking in https://crbug.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77090962/7953469
in fact, i was stuck at the window for "ads privacy acknowledgement", it has a specific flag that helps preventing the window from popping up, i tried searching explanation for that and why it works but i couldn't find anything, i will try my best and post it here if found.
solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77090962/

another solution here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1518516&q=&can=2

Answer (score 0):

Hey i can help you with that. so when you run selenium stuff like this will pop up like cookies policys and notification notes. easyist way to get past this is to make a small function which will bypass it:

```
def pop_up():
    buttons = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
    for button in buttons:
        if button.text == "Got It":
            button.click()
```

this should bypass that page now. Let me know if you need anymore help Happy codeing :)

Comment: thank you @mord, i found a solution, i was asking with the wrong keywords sorry for that, please read the solution comment - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77090962/7953469